# how to retrieve ajax response value from service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am using 2 service in controller
 First Service is to get AjaxResponse where logic to fetching the response is mentioned
The second Service calls the first service to make Http request and get result and then, in turn, return it to the controller

## Ctrl Dependency injected firstService,secondService

```
this.getService = secondService.getData(param);
```

## First Service--> firstService

```
this.httpResponse(param){
   var re = $http.get(param);
  return re.then(success,fail);
}
function success(data){
   return data;
}
function fail(data){
   console.log(data);
}
```

## Second Service (Dependency injection of First Service)

```
function secondService(firstService){
    this.getData = function(param){
       return firstService.httpResponse(param);
    };
}
```

`this.getService` is coming as undefined, all the call are going properly.

Even tried  the following code:

```
secondService.getData(param).then(function(data){console.log(data);});
```

That doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Callback to get the result.It is similar to deferred(promise)

Answer (score 0):

You should chain the promises in these kinds of situations.

First, you define your service.  It should contain two distinct functions.  As an example, I did a `GET` and a `POST`.

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).factory("SharedServices", function($http) {
    return {
        getItem: function() {
            return $http.get('path/to/api');
        },
        postItem: function(payload) {
            return $http.post('path/to/api', payload);
        }
    };
});
```

Then, reference the service in your controller.  `getItem()` will return a promise, where you can use it using `.then` to call your second service in the success callback.

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, SharedServices) {
    SharedServices.getItem().then(function(response) {
        //success, got something
        //call the second part
        var payload = { myPayload: response.data.someItem };
        SharedServices.postItem(payload).then(function(response) {
            //success
        }, function(response) {
            //an error has occurred to the second call--POST
        });
    }, function(response) {
        //an error occurred to the first call--GET
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not my concern, service calling another service to get response

Comment: You shouldn't nest `$http` calls inside services.  Separate those responsibilities, bro.  You should instead chain those promises.

Comment: Can't do it, is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Please elaborate on "can't do it".  I just showed you how via [promise chaining](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/09/28/chaining-promises-in-javascript.aspx).

Comment: That's not a promise chaining,solution you give i already applied on first service. Anyway i figured it out thanks